# Sorting products of different lengths

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

We have an ecommerce site which has been selling items for one day for a few years now. We have a system in place where products can be ordered so the 'featured' products are at the top and the ones which don't sell so well are at the bottom below the fold.

We've recently introduced products which run across a few days rather than just one, however this is causing havoc with our sorting algorithm.

Previously we set the product order on a day by day basis, so if we had 5 products selling on one day, we would set it up like this in the database:

```
Position | Product
----------------------
1        | Product # 1
5        | Product # 2
4        | Product # 3
2        | Product # 4
3        | Product # 5
```

We could then pull the list of products for a day, sort by position and display. However now we have to compensate for products which run across multiple days, therefore could have multiple positions over multiple days. We thought we could easily adjust our algorithm to run across the entire products table like so:

```
Position | Product
----------------------
51       | Product # 1
75       | Product # 2
69       | Product # 3
62       | Product # 4
66       | Product # 5
```

These products are still in the same order as they were originally, but the position is based on every product in the table rather than just that day. This gives us a calendar which is what we expect (the number is the current position in the products table):
[image]

The problem comes when we want to re-order the products. If we had product #6 which ran across 3 days, it might have a position of 64, which puts it under #4 and above #3 on the day, but when we re-order these products it moves and we get jQuery UI data of the position in a list which doesn't relate to anything, and although we know where the product was in relation to other days, we don't know how those days relate together.

We currently have a callback firing after every drop so we only need to deal with one product being moved at a time. This reduces the calculations we need to do but we'd rather set the order in one go and process it from there. This also gives the user a chance to abort.

Here is our current sorting algorithm which inserts the product in between two others:

```
public function setPosition($after, $before)
{
    // Get products which this product is after and before
    $after  = $this->find($after);
    $before = $this->find($before);

    // Move all items down to clear a space for the product
    $this->where('position', '>', $before->position)->update(array('position', DB::raw('position + 1')));

    $this->position = $after->position + 1;
    $this->updateUniques();
}
```

We're sure we're not the only people who have encountered this problem and think there must be a way to solve it.

Comment: -sorry for my dumb question, but how you generate these tables to text?

Comment: Four spaces then some dashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not perfect, but instead of moving the product itself I ended up moving the products which are affected and it seems to work.

Data is passed as an array from jQueryUI sortable.

The controller has this update function:

```
/**
 * Update the schedule order
 *
 * @return object
 */
public function update()
{
    // Find product before and after
    foreach (Input::get('order') as $key => $product)
    {
        if ($product['id'] != Input::get('id')) continue;

        // Find the products before or after this product
        $before = Input::get('order.' . ($key - 1) . '.id') ?: 0;
        $after  = Input::get('order.' . ($key + 1) . '.id') ?: 0;
        break;
    }

    // Find product
    $product = Product::find(Input::get('id'));

    $product->updatePosition($before, $after);

    return $this->get();
}
```

The model has this updatePosition function:

```
/**
 * Move/reorder a product into another position
 *
 * @param int $before [= 0]
 * @param int $after [= 0]
 * @return void
 */
public function updatePosition($before = 0, $after = 0)
{
    // Get products which are before or after this product
    $before = $this->find($before);
    $after  = $this->find($after);

    // Determine which direction we've moved this product
    if ( ! $before) $direction = -1;
    elseif ( ! $after) $direction = 1;
    elseif ($before->position < $this->position && $after->position < $this->position) $direction = -1;
    else $direction = 1;

    // Determine how much we've moved
    if ($direction == 1)
    {
        // We've moved this product down
        $difference = $this->position - $before->position - 1;
        $this->whereNull('parent_id')->where('position', '<=', $before->position)->where('id', '!=', $this->id)->update(array('position' => DB::raw('position + ' . $difference)));
    }
    else
    {
        $difference = $this->position - $after->position + 1;
        $this->whereNull('parent_id')->where('position', '>=', $after->position)->where('id', '!=', $this->id)->update(array('position' => DB::raw('position + ' . $difference)));
    }
}
```

The downside to this is I still have to save after each drop rather than reordering a heap of products and working out their new positions but it works...

Answer (score 0):

I would think that it really matters what "position" the entries have when you display them. The only thing that should matter is the *relative* position of the entries that are shown. So therefore, you could just swap their overall positions. So in your second example,

```
Position | Product
----------------------
51       | Product # 1
75       | Product # 2
69       | Product # 3
62       | Product # 4
66       | Product # 5
```

If you want to swap products 2 and 3, just set #2 position to 69 and #3 position to 75.

```
Position | Product
----------------------
51       | Product # 1
75       | Product # 3
69       | Product # 2
62       | Product # 4
66       | Product # 5
```

If I'm understanding you correctly, I don't think this should affect the other days.

To accomplish this, I would use a `data` attribute on the HTML element, something like `data-position` and set this to the values returned from the database. Then in jQuery, when you swap the rows, you have the two `data-position`s that can easily be sent by AJAX into your SQL query to swap the positions.

This should also work if you decide to re-order all of the entries and just send one callback. Just use their `data-position` for each of the elements when you fire off your callback.

Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: Thanks Mike, that makes perfect sense. The problem is when a product spans multiple days. It's relative position is different to products depending on which day we're looking at. If we have a multi-day product with a position of 10, and we move it above a product on one day with a position of 5, what do we do with the product on the next day with a position of 6 which it should still be below?

Comment: @sjdaws There's no way a small sample of data can be positioned relative to the whole data set without having knowledge of the whole set. If you have positions 10, 15, 20, and 25, there is no way of knowing that you want to move the item from position 25 to 17 without using the items in between. All you know is that it's between 16 and 19. So basically you would have to either tweak it one day at a time, or use the entire set instead of a small sample.

Comment: For example, in the image you have above, if you want to move "Soft careful ahead theory 127" up by one position, how do you know that there is not something else between that and "Within equator suggest 124"? Maybe there is, maybe there isn't. The only thing you can do is move it up above the other one and if there is something in between those two, go to a date that has the other one available and flip them around.

Comment: And if I'm understanding you, perhaps you should add some code and some examples of what the expected output would be because it is a rather confusing question.

Comment: Hi Mike, sorry my question was unclear to you. I am setting the order a day at a time, but that day can affect other days. See my answer below.